# Issue in scheduling a Managed Package Class

Tags: managed-package, scheduled-job

I have a "GeoCoderSchedulable" class in a managed package. I want to schedule the class in my salesforce org by code, not by salesforce Scheduler GUI. I used the below code in Anonymous block to schedule but getting the below error -
"Line: 1, Column: 1
Enclosing type for global methods in apex classes must be declared as global"

```
 global class ScheduleGeoCoder implements system.schedulable{
    GeoCoderSchedulable testobj = new GeoCoderSchedulable();
    public String cronexpression = '0 0 0 ? * 1,2,3,4,5,7';
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
      System.schedule('Account Geocoding Batch_New2', cronexpression, testobj);
    }
    }
```

Please let me know where is the issue in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous Apex does not support defining new classes, but you don't need a `Schedulable` to schedule another `Schedulable`. In fact, that's highly unlikely to get you what you want. To schedule the class `GeoCoderSchedulable` in Anonymous Apex, you just need to call `System.schedule()` directly:

```
System.schedule('Account Geocoding Batch_New2', '0 0 0 ? * 1,2,3,4,5,7', new GeoCoderSchedulable());
```

You'll need to replace `GeoCoderSchedulable` with the fully-qualified name of the class, including its namespace.

Comment: When I am running your code I am getting error "Line: 1, Column: 74
Invalid type: GeoCoderSchedulable"

Comment: @AritraChakraborty As David said, you need to include the namespace of the class, such as `new somens.GeoCoderSchedulable())`.